# Collection high-level operation deprecation (list:List[A] - a:A)

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Why do we have this operator-method

```
      @deprecated("use `filterNot (_ == x)` instead", "2.8.0")
  def - [B >: A](x: B): List[B] 
//i.e. List(1,23,3,4,5) - 23
```

deprecated for lists, but not for sets?

```
Set(1,23,3,4) - 23
```

If it because List is not very suitable for this operation in terms of performance, but we still have length method we should avoid.
How collection operators  will look like in future versions of scala?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with the `List` method is that it never did what you would expect it to do.  Naively, I would expect

```
1,2,3,1,2,3 - 1,2,3,1 == 2,3
```

and therefore

```
1,2,3,1,2,3 - 1 == 2,3,1,2,3
```

Except that's not what you get; instead you get

```
1,2,3,1,2,3 - 1 == 2,3,2,3
```

(which is exactly what `filterNot` gives, and which you should expect).

Since elements of a `Set` are unique, there is no distinction between the two methods.